# Format string in Swift is not working correctly

Tags: string, swift

I am new in Swift and I am coming from Android background.

I want to format a string.

My code is as following:

```
let PARAM = "{\"title\": \"%a\", \"name\": \"%a\", \"message\": \"%a\", \"email\": \"%a\"}"
```

and

```
let parameter = String.localizedStringWithFormat(POST_CONTACT_US_PARAM, "title", "name","message", "email");
```

The result is :

> {"title": "0x0p+0", "name": "0x0p+0", "message": "0x0p+0", "email": "0x0p+0"}

Can any one tell me what is the problem?

Comment: @Thomasa Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `%@` instead of `%a` as a placeholder for text.

Also, I suggest using the new String initializer for this task, like this:

```
let PARAM = "{\"title\": \"%@\", \"name\": \"%@\", \"message\": \"%@\", \"email\": \"%@\"}"

let parameter = String(format: PARAM, locale: NSLocale.currentLocale(), "title", "name","message", "email")

print(parameter)
```

Result:

> {"title": "title", "name": "name", "message": "message", "email": "email"}

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), `%a` is used to format:

> 64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in scientific notation with a leading 0x and one hexadecimal digit before the decimal point using a lowercase p to introduce the exponent.

Most of the time, you will want to use `%@` as your format specifier (except for types that are not classes/struct).

Hence the right definition for `PARAM` becomes

```
let PARAM = "{\"title\": \"%@\", \"name\": \"%@\", \"message\": \"%@\", \"email\": \"%@\"}"
```